# uCommerce_Payment table not populated

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

Hopefully someone could shed some light on where we're going wrong here. Our implementation is using Paypal but having set up the integration as described in the docs (http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v5/payment-providers/setup-paypal-standard-website-payments-as-a-payment-method.html) attempting a payment was resulting in a plain postback at the "Preview" stage (i.e. click to pay but page posts back and nothing happens).

My understanding is that somewhere in the pipeline the uCommerce_Payment table must be populated for the PurchaseOrder in question and from there the following code (in uCommerce/Preview.cshtml)...

```
TransactionLibrary.ExecuteBasketPipeline();
TransactionLibrary.RequestPayments();
```

...should pick up the entry in this table and direct the payment accordingly.

Problem is, when I check the database there are no records in our uCommerce_Payment table.

Any ideas?